# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, slf4j, classnotfoundexception

SpringSource throws this error when I load my web-application.The exception occurs at the point where I instantiate the logger.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class MyDemo{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDemo.class);
...
}
```

When I build the application thro Maven, the error seems a bit different:

```
Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
```

I have checked the answers on this topic here and elsewhere, including the suggestions on [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder). I have looked through the dependencies, and all the dependent log libraries are included (slf4j-api, slf4j-simple, slf4j-log4j). I have also verified the Build Path for each of the modules in my project and the specific module with this class. Does anyone have any fresh insights on issue?

I do see there is a mix-up of logging mechanism some modules using logback and others log4j,  is this a cause for concern?

Comment: You have both slf4j-simple and slf4j-log4j in your classpath? Though I am not sure if it is the problem but it is definitely not the way to go.  Choose only one binding to put in your runtime classpath.

Comment: Yes I included slf4j-simple, based on the suggetions in SLF4J manual, bu it doesnt help to resolve the issue, so I removed it. Currently I have only slf4j-log4j in the module that throws this error.

Comment: are you sure that u have the binding in the classpath? which version of slf4j u r using?

Comment: SLF4J 1.6.6. I see some of the common modules that I work with are using logback, while certains others use log4j, so the bindings for both are there.

Comment: First, I believe no module will use logback.  They mostly depends on SLF4J api (which is the interface LogBack implements), and for library using log4j, it won't cause SLF4J log4J binding to exists.  That means, both of your assumption have nothing to do with the SLF4J bindings.  Can you PLEASE actually check what binding is in the final runtime classpath?  If you are using Maven, a dependency:tree should help

Comment: I looked at the dependency hierarchy for my application and the specific new module when included causes this exception. They have the following logging dependencies slf4-api, jcl-over-slf4j, logback-core, logback-classic.

Comment: Are you putting these dependencies yourselves? Normally, artifacts that aim to use as library only depends on slf4j-api.  All other bindings (e.g. logback-classic) and api bridges (e.g. jcl-over-slf4j) dependencies is omitted and left for the final executable artifact. If the lib causing the problem is developed in-house, fix the dependency issue.  If it is a 3rd party lib, you may exclude those slf4j bindings transitive dependency by using `<dependency><excludes>...</excludes></dependency>` in Maven

Comment: @jeera Can you post your pox.xml so we can have a better insight?

Comment: I just copied the jar files into **WebContent->WEB-INF->lib** folder & then it worked.